# STM32L486 enable LPUART1 with DMA

Tags: debugging, stm32, uart, dma, firmware

I'm trying to enable LPUART1 to write/read traces and debug my code.

Im setting PC0/PC1 pin:

```
/*Configure GPIO pins : PC0 PC1 */
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_LPUART1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Created the handlers:

```
UART_HandleTypeDef hlpuart1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_lpuart_tx;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_lpuart_rx;
```

My init function. I call it from main.c:

```
/* LPUART1 init function */
void MX_LPUART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  hlpuart1.Instance = LPUART1;
  hlpuart1.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  hlpuart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  hlpuart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  hlpuart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  hlpuart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  hlpuart1.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  hlpuart1.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&hlpuart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

}
```

The function HAL_UART_Init:

```
  /* USER CODE BEGIN LPUART1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END LPUART1_MspInit 0 */
    /* LPUART1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**LPUART1 GPIO Configuration
    PC0     ------> LPUART1_RX
    PC1     ------> LPUART1_TX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF8_LPUART1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* LPUART1 DMA Init */
    /* LPUART_RX Init */
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Instance = DMA2_Channel7;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_lpuart_rx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_lpuart_rx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(uartHandle,hdmarx,hdma_usart1_rx);
    /* LPUART_TX Init */
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Instance = DMA2_Channel6;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_4;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Direction = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Mode = DMA_NORMAL;
    hdma_lpuart_tx.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_lpuart_tx) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(uartHandle,hdmatx,hdma_lpuart_tx);

    /* LPUART1 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(LPUART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPUART1_IRQn);
```

I have set the NVIC LPUART1 at the end of the last code. I have enable too the DMA2 channel 6 and 7 interrupts:

```
/** 
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
void MX_DMA_Init(void) 
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA1_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA1_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel1_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel2_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel4_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn);
  /* DMA1_Channel5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel5_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel1_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel1_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel1_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel2_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel2_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel2_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel6_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel6_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel6_IRQn);
  /* DMA2_Channel7_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Channel7_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Channel7_IRQn);

}
```

In my main.c im trying to print something and it always return "HAL_OK":

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&hlpuart1, (uint8_t *)'ACK\n', 5);
```

Inside the last function, we have set this callback:

```
  /* Set the UART DMA transfer complete callback */
  huart->hdmatx->XferCpltCallback = UART_DMATransmitCplt;
```

And inside this one, we have this callback:

```
HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(huart);

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {

    /* Set transmission flag: transfer complete */
    BaseType_t xHigherPriorityTaskWoken = pdFALSE;

    if(huart->Instance == USART1)
    {
        if(UART_TX_Acess != NULL)
        {
            xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(UART_TX_Acess, &xHigherPriorityTaskWoken); //Usart transmision complete
        }
    }
    else if(huart->Instance == LPUART1)
    {
        modbus_tx_finish = 0;
    }

    portYIELD_FROM_ISR( xHigherPriorityTaskWoken );
}
```

Everything seems to be fine coded but DMA2_Channel6_IRQHandler is jumping and and inside DMA IRQhandler an error appears:

/* Transfer Error Interrupt management **************************************/

But I cant understand why...

Comment: Maybe find the code that leads to the error, and see which bits in which register are tested to trigger it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I noticed the error. I was writting wrong the function to write. THis was the original:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&hlpuart1, (uint8_t *)'ACK\n', 5);
```

And this is the change:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&hlpuart1, (uint8_t *)"ACK\n", 5);
```

Comment: Hasn't your compiler warned you about this?

Comment: This question and answer have no value for the community because it is a typo.